# C# float max parse error

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, formatting, tostring

I declared a byte array which contains 4 bytes.

```
byte[] bts = new byte[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x7f }; 
float f1 = BitConverter.ToSingle(bts, 0); 
string s = f1.ToString(); 
float f2 = float.Parse(s); 
byte[] bts2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(f2);
```

After some conversion, I realized that the output changes from

```
{ 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x7f }
```

to

```
{ 0xfD, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x7f }
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `f1` and `f1.ToString()` in the watch window you will see that

> `f1` = 3.40282347E+38
>
> `f1.ToString()` = 3.402823E+38

Which means that the `ToString` method outputs a `string` representing a trimmed number and is not as accurate as the 4 byte `float`, ***But why?***

The default [`float.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5dbkt9x(v=vs.110).aspx) uses [The `G` specifier in the standard numeric format `strings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) which has 7 digit accuracy for `floats`.

You can use an [other overload of `ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f71z6k0c(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the format specifier and provide it the amount of digits you want to represent:

```
string s = f1.ToString("G10");
```

A better way would be to use the `"R"` specifier which is lossless

```
string s = f1.ToString("R");
```

> MSDN: The round-trip ("R") format specifier is used to ensure that a numeric value that is converted to a string will be parsed back into the same numeric value.